# How to find the first tag that contains a git commit?

Tags: git

I have the SHA ID of a commit that I am interested in and would like to know how to find the first tag that contains it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474115/find-tag-information-for-a-given-commit

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923091/how-to-list-all-tags-that-contain-a-commit

Answer (score 26):

As previously stated, this can be done with `git describe`.  In your particular case, however, you may find it more convenient to run  `git name-rev --tags --name-only <SHA>`, which outputs exactly what you want.  See [git-name-rev(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-name-rev.html).

Answer (score 17):

`git describe --contains "$committish"` shows a reference to the commit built on a tag plus a `~$n` ancestorhood count, so the following command shows the most recent tag that contains a commit:

```
git describe --contains "$committish" | sed 's/~.*//'
```

If there is no tag that contains this commit, `git describe` will fail. If you'd like to get the (abbreviated) committish instead, add the `--always` option.